# How to display "Please wait...." on the web page when click on a button using Python&HTML

Tags: python, html, web-applications, textbox, reload

I need to show the text "Please wait ....." when I click on  the ON button until the guvcview open, then showing "guvcview is running" instead .The same thing when I close the guvcview?.In the following python code,I tried to display "Please wait ....." but I couldn't.
Some people said that is need to reload the page again. This is just example, in my code I have authentication for the page login and logout.
I need the simplest way please, Thanks.

```
import cherrypy
import os.path
import struct
import time
import subprocess
import commands

class Server(object):
    led_on=1 
    led_off=1 
    def index(self,  on='', off=''):
        html = """
         <html>
           <body>
             <br>
             <p>{htmlText}
             <p>
             <a href="?on=1"><img src="images/on.png"></a>
             <a href="?off=1"><img src="images/off.png"></a>
           </body>
          </html>
                """
        myText = ''
        if on:
            self.led_on = int(on)             
            myText = "Please wait ....."
            html.format(htmlText=myText)
            subprocess.call(['guvcview &'], shell=True)
            time.sleep(2)
            output = commands.getoutput('ps -A')
            if 'guvcview' in output:
                myText = "guvcview is running"

        if off:
            self.led_off = int(off)             
            myText = "Please wait ....."
            html.format(htmlText=myText)
            subprocess.call(['sudo pkill guvcview'], shell=True)
            time.sleep(2)
            output = commands.getoutput('ps -A')
            if 'guvcview' in output:
                myText = "Please wait ....."
            else:
                myText = "guvcview closed"

        return html.format(htmlText=myText)
    index.exposed = True
conf = {
        'global' : { 
            'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0', 
            'server.socket_port': 8085 
        },

        '/images': {
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath('images')
        }
    }
cherrypy.quickstart(Server(), config=conf)
```

Comment: shouldn't this be done client-side, i.e.: javascript?

Comment: Is it possible without using javascript?

Comment: Not that I know of. Clicking a button in a browser is a client-side event, and can only be intercepted using javascript. The alternative, which can be done only client-side, is doing a HTTP POST, but that would make the browser navigate to a new page, which is not what you want, I suspect

Comment: doubt its possible to do without some client side technology (javascript or actionscript maybe ...)

Comment: In case of using javascript, should it added to this python code or use it without Python? I need to use the python code because this is just a piece of a bit longer python code.

Comment: @majidhantoosh as said previously, javascript executes **client-side**. Python executes server-side. Javascript must be sent to the browser along with the html page, or in a separate .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the others have suggested you're going to need client side scripting to get this to work.  However you don't need to redirect to another page if you implement an ajax solution.  Give this a try and see if this is what you are after.

```
import cherrypy
import os.path
import struct
import time
import subprocess
import commands

class Server(object):
    led_on=1 
    led_off=1 
    def index(self):
        html = """
         <html>
           <body>
           <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
           function Activate(CurrentState)
           {
               // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
               if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
               else// code for IE6, IE5
                   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
               {
                   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                   {
                       document.getElementById("UserMessage").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                   }
               }

               xmlhttp.open("GET","/Process?on=" + CurrentState, true);
               xmlhttp.send();
           }
           </script>
             <br>
             <p id="UserMessage"><p>
             <a onclick="document.getElementById('UserMessage').innerHTML = 'Please wait .....';Activate('1');"><img src="images/on.png"></a>
             <a onclick="document.getElementById('UserMessage').innerHTML = 'Please wait .....';Activate('0');"><img src="images/off.png"></a>
           </body>
          </html>
                """
        return html
    index.exposed = True

    def Process(self,  on='0'):
        if on == '1':
            self.led_on = int(on)             
            subprocess.call(['guvcview &'], shell=True)
            time.sleep(2)
            output = commands.getoutput('ps -A')
            if 'guvcview' in output:
                return "guvcview is running"

        if on == '0':
            self.led_off = int(on)
            subprocess.call(['sudo pkill guvcview'], shell=True)
            time.sleep(2)
            output = commands.getoutput('ps -A')
            if 'guvcview' in output:
                return "Please wait ....."
            else:
                return "guvcview closed"

        return "Please wait ....."
    Process.exposed = True

conf = {
        'global' : { 
            'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0', 
            'server.socket_port': 8085 
        },

        '/images': {
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath('images')
        }
    }
cherrypy.quickstart(Server(), config=conf)
```

Hope this helps!

Andrew

Comment: Thank you Andrew for reply, unfortunately, the code doesn't work, nothing happen when I click neither "On" nor "Off" buttons!

Comment: Ok, try the code again - I've updated it with a couple fixes.  I setup a test environment and verified the html, js and cherrypy is working correctly... but I can't test your subprocesses.

Comment: Excellent, the code work so fine, Thank you so much Andrew, you are very helpful man. Thanks again.